# discord.py не могу сделать чтоб бот отправлял рандомное слово

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import random
import config
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")

hello_words = ["привет","хай","хеллоу"]
answer_words = ["где я?","что тут происходить?"]
goodbye_words = ["пока","всем пока"]
ban_words = ["****","1****","2****","3*****","3****","4****"]
udu_words = ["иди нафиг","иди ***","пошёл ****","пошёл нафиг","пошёл ***"]
words_list = [ "Что сказал наркоман когда на него упала стена? -Пацаны меня накрыло",
 "Штирлиц напоил кошку бензином,она прошла два метра и сдохла -Штирлиц подумал что бензин кончился",
"Какую инструкцию нельзя давать инвалидам -пошаговую",
"Мужик шёл по лесу,видит краба и спрашивает: ты тут каким боком?"]


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in hello_words:
        await message.channel.send("Привет,я АнекБот")

    if msg in answer_words:
        await message.channel.send("Ты на лучшем сервере, где будет происходить много веселья и ты весело проведёшь время")

    if msg in goodbye_words:
        await message.channel.send("Иди ***!")

    if msg in ban_words:
        await message.channel.send("Это оскорбительное слово! Не используй его больше,пожалуйста!")

    if msg in udu_words:
        await message.channel.send("Сам иди!")


#Надо чтоб бот при команде отправлял рандомный анекдот с words_list в чат


token=open('config.py')
client.run(config.discord_token)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, поправьте вопрос. Напишите краткий заголовок, передающий суть проблемы, а всю остальную информацию, в том числе и, собственно, сам вопрос (который у Вас, кстати, не уместился) перенесите в тело сообщения.

Comment: мне нравится то что он матерится

Comment: *Перефразировал вопрос, думаю сейчас всё станет понятно*
P.s: Недавно начал изучать Python и решил взять на себя создание простенького бота, но столкнулся с проблемой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте модуль `random`.

```
import random

anek_int = random.randint(1, 4)
await message.channel.send(words_list(anek_int))
```

Генерируйте рандомное число от 1 до 4(потому что у вас представлено 4 "анекдота"), помещаете это число в переменную, в нашем случае `anek_int` и обращаетесь к списку "анекдотов" к определённому элементу.

Comment: @bot.event
async def randoms(ctx,message):
    anek_int = random.randint(1, 4)
        await message.channel.send (words_list(anek_int))
переделал и понял. Но всё ровно без результатно, код запускается без ошибок, но я так и не могу бота заставит давать мне "Анекдоты"

Comment: Включены ли у вас ```message content``` интенты на портале разработчика?

Comment: Да,включены. Но так и ничего не пишет, я даже незнаю какую команду надо ввести чтоб он присылал "Анекдот"